# file not found error when running container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a test automation project which gets uses the code built as part of jar file and that jar gets invoked via bat file. All these files are stored within my project folder.

contents of my Docker file:

```
FROM maven:3.8.1-adoptopenjdk-11
#WORKDIR C:/Work/Kickstart_TEM/Prefs
COPY Prefs /home/Prefs
COPY KickStart.jar /home/Prefs/KickStart.jar
CMD home\prefs\run.bat && cmd
```

docker build generates following output

```
[+] Building 0.3s (8/8) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 210B                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/maven:3.8.1-adoptopenjdk-11                                     0.0s
 => [1/3] FROM docker.io/library/maven:3.8.1-adoptopenjdk-11                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 390B                                                                                  0.0s
 => CACHED [2/3] COPY Prefs /home/Prefs                                                                            0.0s
 => CACHED [3/3] COPY KickStart.jar /home/Prefs/KickStart.jar                                                      0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                             0.1s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                            0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:4c878e8a895b2fad307e00f1b2fb5c9b5df7dc630e87414230d1989b75a5ee17                       0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/demo2
```

Docker run generates following error:

```
PS C:\Work\Docker_POC> docker run -i -p 4044:4044 demo2
/bin/sh: 1: homeprefsrun.bat: not found
```

My containers stops right away, so I am not even able to figure out if my files and folders got copied successfully or not. And I am unsure of how to resolve this error.

Comment: I would say that `/home/Prefs` != `home\prefs`

Comment: i have tried with both home/prefs/run.bat and home\prefs\run.bat and i get the same error

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're trying to run a batch script under Linux (the docker image you're using determines this).

In general, your CMD statement should look like `CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "/home/Prefs/run.sh && cmd"]` (although I'm not sure what `cmd` is and why you want to run it)

You should convert this batch script (run.bat) to a shell script. Also, there is a difference between `home` and `/home` and filenames are case-sensitive (thus it's `Prefs` and not `prefs`).